# Should the main verb be singular or plural when there is a singular subject and a plural subject?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

"The ways in which information is presented by the media ***shape*** how we view our world."

Or should it be as follows?

"The ways in which information is presented by the media ***shapes*** how we view our world."

Comment: Have you asked yourself what is doing the shaping?

Comment: The subject here is 'The ways in which information is presented by the media'.  Try a more obvious example of the same form: 'The books in which information is provided by the experts **is/are** on sale at Liquorstones.'

Comment: Isabel and Edwin,
The focus is on the subject, "ways" more than it is on the subject, "information", so I believe I should use the first example I showed. 
"The ways in which information is presented by the media shape how we view our world."

Comment: "information" is the subject of a subordinate clause "in which information is presented by the media" but it's not the subject of the main clause; the main verb does not agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no singular subject in this sentence; the subject is the plural noun *ways,* or rather the noun phrase containing it. So only "shape" is correct.